# Qual o número da linha clicada

Tags: php, javascript

[image: 1]]

Preciso enviar pelo 'post' esse número de linha para outro programa `php`

---

```
<div id="posiciona">
    <table id="mostra_prod" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3" bordercolor="#000">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" bgcolor="#0a0a96">Aplicação</td>
            <td align="left"  bgcolor="#0a0a96">Referência</td> 
        </tr> 
        <?php 
        $i=0;         
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_pd)) { 
            $rfprod  = $row['pro_referencia_produto'];
            $idref[] = $rfprod;  
            $i++;  
            $approd  = $row['pro_aplicacao_produto'];
            ?><tr><?php 
            echo "<td align='right' style='color: #cfcfd1;'>".$approd."</td>";
            echo "<td style='color: #ffffff;'>".$rfprod."</td>";
            ?></tr><?php 
       }
       ?>         
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Podias usar algo como `onClick="minhaFuncao(this, <?= $i; ?>)"`. O que já tentaste?

Comment: Você pode trabalhar com [**Cookie**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) ou com [**Session**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp), assim você armazena as informações que você quer em variáveis e pode recuperá-las em qualquer outro "programa" php.

Comment: Paulo, porque que em certas partes do código você utiliza o `echo` do `PHP` para imprimir o `<td>` e em outras partes você utiliza `?> <td> <?php`, assim fica confuso até mesmo para você dar alguma manutenção futura, aconselho a fazer apenas de uma maneira.

Comment: Paulo é apenas por POST? O que você me diz sobre o GET?

Comment: Caro Marcos, fico agradecido pelo seu retorno...mas sou marinheiro de primeira nesse tipo de código...por isso essas mancadas...Não entendo ainda se poderia ser melhor pelo GET.

Comment: Ta certo, mas tente usar de uma maneira apenas, o `echo` do PHP imprime os elementos `HTML`, então você pode usar sempre o `echo` ao invés de fechar e abrir o `PHP`, ou utilize o `echo` somente onde vai usar o código em `PHP` mesmo, abre `<?php` coloca o código e após fecha `?>`... Ah e procure marcar como **RESPOSTA CERTA** a resposta que realmente lhe resolveu o problema ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, temos algumas coisas para fazer aqui:

1º vamos dar uma ajeitada na sua marcação, colocando os elementos devidos para cada parte da tabela:

```
<div id="posiciona">
    <table id="mostra_prod" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3" bordercolor="#000">
        <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th align="right" bgcolor="#0a0a96">Aplicação</th>
                 <th align="left"  bgcolor="#0a0a96">Referência</th> 
             </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
        $i=0;         
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_pd)) { 
            $rfprod  = $row['pro_referencia_produto'];
            $idref[] = $rfprod;  
            $i++;  
            $approd  = $row['pro_aplicacao_produto'];
            ?><tr><?php 
            echo "<td align='right' style='color: #cfcfd1;'>".$approd."</td>";
            echo "<td style='color: #ffffff;'>".$rfprod."</td>";
            ?></tr><?php 
       }
       ?>   
        </tbody>      
    </table>
</div>
```

Colocamos os elementos `thead` e `tbody` que são o cabeçalho e o corpo da tabela respectivamente.

2º Adicionar o javascript:

```
function enviar(caminho, parametros, metodo) {
    metodo = metodo|| 'post'; // O padrão será post.

    var form = document.createElement( 'form' );
    form.setAttribute( 'method', metodo );
    form.setAttribute( 'action', caminho );

    //Cria os campos com base em um objeto passado
    for( var propriedade in parametros ) 
        if( parametros.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
            var campo = document.createElement( 'input' );
            campo.setAttribute( 'type', 'hidden' );
            campo.setAttribute( 'name', key );
            campo.setAttribute( 'value', parametros[propriedade] );

            form.appendChild( hiddenField );
         }

    document.body.appendChild( form );
    //Envia o formulário
    form.submit();
}

//pegar uma array com as linhas:
const linhas = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#mostra_prod tbody tr' ) );

const onClick = function() {
     //Quando clicar em uma linha (tr) vai enviar o conteudo da sua segunda celula (td):
     enviar( 'meu_arquivo.php', { linha : this.children[1].innerText } );
}
//Adicionamos o listener
linhas.forEach( linha => linha.addEventListener( 'click', onClick ) );
```

3º agora é só pegar a variavel em meu_arquivo.php :

```
$linha = $_POST['linha'];
```

Obs: sinceramente, recomendo a biblioteca jQuery e recomendo o uso de requisições assincronas, não que não vá funcionar, mas isso deixa a aplicação mais rica, providenciando uma melhor experiencia ao usuário !

Comment: Caro Lucas, boa tarde!

Comment: Caro Lucas, boa tarde! Agradeço desde já, o atendimento à minha solicitação. Eu, inseri o seu código, e não está chamando o segundo programa. Também quero te informar que, por ser marinheiro de primeira viagem, achei que poderia passar o parâmetro de array 'rfprod' subscritando o número da linha. Mancada...! Então, reformulando, eu preciso enviar o campo de referencia do item, $rfprod pelo POST.

Comment: @PauloLadeira Editado o click handler : )

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer de maneira simples é inserir um campo de formulário do tipo `radio` na tabela, junto com um `label`, assim, quando a linha da tabela for pressionada, o campo será selecionado, contendo o `id` do registro em questão. Por exemplo, na coluna `Aplicação`, coloque algo como:

```
<td align='right' style='color: #cfcfd1;'>
  <label>
    Produto 1
    <input type="radio" name="aplicacao" value="1">
  </label>
</td>
```

Quando a linha for pressionada, o campo `radio` será selecionado contendo o valor 1. CAso não deseja que o campo fique visível na tabela, basta ocultá-lo:

```
<input type="radio" name="aplicacao" value="1" style="display:none;">
```

Veja um exemplo em funcionamento:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<table id="mostra_prod" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3" bordercolor="#000">
  <tr>
    <td align="right" bgcolor="#0a0a96">Aplicação</td>
    <td align="left"  bgcolor="#0a0a96">Referência</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='right' style='color: #cfcfd1;'>
      <label>
        Produto 1
        <input type="radio" name="aplicacao" value="1">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td style='color: #ffffff;'>0001</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='right' style='color: #cfcfd1;'>
      <label>
        Produto 2
        <input type="radio" name="aplicacao" value="2">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td style='color: #ffffff;'>0002</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='right' style='color: #cfcfd1;'>
      <label>
        Produto 3
        <input type="radio" name="aplicacao" value="3">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td style='color: #ffffff;'>0003</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Assim, estando o código devidamente dentro de um formulário, o campo `aplicacao` será enviado com o valor da linha selecionada.

Comment: Caro Anderson, Agraço a sua colaboração, vou testar o seu código...